# Send url via get parameter asp-net Api

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, url

I'm having troubles passing an image Url to my API controller.

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("cont/getByUrl/{url}")]
    public string Get(string url)
    {
         //code         

    }
```

**My Ajax call**

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:64444/api/cont/getByUrl/"+ encodeURIComponent("http://www.moooi.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/product-images/random_detail.jpg?itok=ErJveZTY"),
      type: 'GET'
   });
```

If my parameter is an simple string, I get there, but if I send an Url Always have 404, I'm using IIS 7.5.

I need to do some changes on my Web.config or I can't do this?

Answer (score 0):

use encodeURI instead of encodeURIComponent and then try

as Don't call encodeURIComponent since it would destroy the URL

Your Ajax call should be like this

$.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:64444/api/cont/getByUrl/"+ encodeURI("http://www.moooi.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/product-images/random_detail.jpg?itok=ErJveZTY"),
      type: 'GET'
   });

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Route you can Use ActionName.

An exemple for an user controller :

```
// Get: api/Users/GetPostUser
[HttpGet, ActionName("GetPostUser")]
```

The link will be like that : http://localhost:64444/api/Users/GetPostUser ( using the correct port )